# subtraction of scalar from tensor yields 'inconsistent tensor size' in pytorch

Tags: torch, subtraction, pytorch

I'm using PyTorch and my variables are

```py
    x = [torch.FloatTensor of size 1x3x32x32]
    mean = Variable containing:
    1.00000e-02 *
      2.0518
    [torch.FloatTensor of size 1]
```

what I want to do is subtract the scalar mean from x by doing

```py
    x = x - mean
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```py
    RuntimeError: inconsistent tensor size at /py/conda-
    bld/pytorch_1493670682084/work/torch/lib/TH/generic/THTensorMath.c:831
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you are trying only works if mean is truly a scalar, i.e. a `float()` (in this case) and not a `torch.FloatTensor of size 1`. You can either extract a true scalar from `mean` or expand `mean` to the size of `x` in order to perform the subtraction.

To extract the `float` from `mean`, do:

```
x = x - mean[0]
```

To expand `mean` to the size of `x`, do:

```
x = x - mean.expand_as(x)
```

Note that both of these methods subtract the mean from each element in your tensor.

Comment: Expanding mean to the size of x worked! Extracting a true scalar from mean  didn't, but I've heard this broadcasting functionality was only recently added, so I'll have to update my pytorch version soon. Thanks